# sending multiple respone from nodejs using python-shell

Tags: node.js

I am trying to execute few python script inside nodejs. The code is shown below. What I am trying to do is executing different python script inside a for loop one by one. and send the json response to client as soon as one script gets over.

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var express = require('express'), app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

  pl_list=["test", "test2"]
  for (var i=0; i<= pl_list.length-1; i++) {
    output="";

var pyshell = new PythonShell('./'+pl_list[i]+'.py')
pyshell.on('message', function (message) 

{console.log(message);output+=message;});
    pyshell.end(function (err) {
        if (err){ 
            console.log('error occured ----  '+err);

        }
        else{
            console.log('update finished');
            res.write(JSON.stringify({"finsihed":true, "product_line":pl_list[i]}));
        }
    });

  }
  //res.end()
});

app.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log('The web server is running. Please open http://localhost:5000/ in your browser.');
});
```

unfortunately I am getting the response as `{"finsihed":true}` actual output must be 
`{"finsihed":true, "product_line":"test"}{"finsihed":true, "product_line":"test2"}` 
can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The execution of your python scripts is asynchronous, so when you write the response to the client with this line, the value of i changed:

```
res.write(JSON.stringify({"finsihed":true, "product_line":pl_list[i]})
```

Just display the value of i with console.log before the above line and you will see that i equals 2 twice (due to the increment of your for-loop). And because `pl_list[i]` is undefined, the serialization of a JSON object removes the attribute "product_line".

If you want to "save" the value of i, you have to learn what [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) is.

This code should work:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

    var nbFinishedScripts = 0;

    pl_list = ["test", "test2"]
    for (var i = 0; i <= pl_list.length - 1; i++) {
        output = "";

        var pyshell = new PythonShell('./' + pl_list[i] + '.py')
        pyshell.on('message', function (message)

            {
                console.log(message);
                output += message;
            });

        // closure
        (function (i) {
            return function () {
                pyshell.end(function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('error occured ----  ' + err);

                    } else {
                        console.log('update finished');
                        res.write(JSON.stringify({
                            "finsihed": true,
                            "product_line": pl_list[i]
                        }));
                    }

                    nbFinishedScripts++;

                    // end the reponse when the number of finished scripts is equal to the number of scripts
                    if (nbFinishedScripts === pl_list.length) {
                        res.end();
                    }
                });
            };
        })(i)(); // immediately invoke the function
    }
});

app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('The web server is running. Please open http://localhost:5000/ in your browser.');
});
```

Edit code:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

var executePythonScript = function (script) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var pyshell = new PythonShell('./' + script + '.py');
        pyshell.end(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(script);
            }
        });
    });
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

    var pl_list = ["test", "test2"];

    Promise
        .all(pl_list.map(executePythonScript))
        .then(function (scripts) {
            scripts.forEach(function (script) {
                res.write(JSON.stringify({
                    finsihed: true,
                    product_line: script
                }));
            });

            res.end();
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            res.end();
        });
});

app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('The web server is running. Please open http://localhost:5000/ in your browser.');
});
```

Comment: thank for the help, but when I executed the above code the response is `{"finsihed":true,"product_line":"test2"}{"finsihed":true,"product_line":"test"}` instead of `{"finsihed":true,"product_line":"test"}{"finsihed":true,"product_line":"test2"}`

Comment: response has to be in same order as value in `pl_list`

Comment: If you want your response to always be in the same order, you have to use some tools that handle asynchronous operations well. I edit my code and choose to use promises. Tell me if it's working for you.